# Cycle files from different folders inside a batch

Tags: loops, batch-file, directory

In a .bat file, I've something like this:

```
set Files="..\DataSet\*.shp"

for /r %%i in (%Files%) do (
    echo Preparing table %%i
    REM other commands
)
```

This allows me to perform operations with every file with extension `.shp` inside the folder set in `%Files%.

the problem is that this is a single folder. I'd like to define different folders in the same variables, and cycle all files in them. Something like

```
set Files="..\DataSet1\*.shp;..\DataSet2\*.shp;..\DataSet3\*.shp"

for /r %%i in (%Files%) do (
    echo Preparing table %%i
    REM other commands
)
```

This way I should able to process every `.shp` file present in all folders defined in the `%Files%` variable. How can I change my code in order to cycle all files of specific extension in all folders defined in my variable?

Comment: `set Files="..\DataSet1\*.shp" "..\DataSet2\*.shp" "..\DataSet3\*.shp"`

Comment: It does not seem to work. I don't enter inside the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `/r`. See the posted answer for an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set folders="..\DataSet1" "..\DataSet2" "..\DataSet3"
    set extensions=".shp"

    for %%f in (%folders%) do for %%x in (%extensions%) do pushd "%%~ff" && (
        for /r %%i in ("*%%~x") do (
            echo Preparing table %%i
            rem .....
        )
        popd
    )
```

As there is no way to include the folder being iterated by `for` command into the `/r` clause of an inner `for` command, previous code changes the current active directory to the folder to iterate.

If changing the current active directory is a problem, the file iteration can be moved to a subroutine

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set folders="..\DataSet1" "..\DataSet2" "..\DataSet3"
    set extensions=".shp"

    for %%f in (%folders%) do for %%x in (%extensions%) do (
        call :process "%%~ff" "%%~x"
    )
    goto :eof

:process folderBeingProcessed extensionToProcess    
    for /r "%~1" %%i in ("*%~2") do (
            echo Preparing table %%i
            rem .....
    )
    goto :eof
```